# Cannot see Buttons in UIScrollView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uibutton, uilabel, addsubview

I was making a list in the form of scrollview in swift where the view consists of various types such as labels, button etc.

However when i added the button to the subview, they were not displayed although all other labels etc were displayed. I also tried messing around in the constraints and anchors.
On the other hand when i added the same button to self.view.addsubview instead of scrollview.addsubview, they were displayed just not scrolling since not a part of the scrollview anymore.
I even removed the label to make sure that the buttons were not being overlapped(didn't work either)

I also tried to see the code in "code debug hierarchy " (3D mode), i couldn't see the button there either even though i had added  it

Below is my code with an example of label, scrollview and button. It be great if anyone could provide any insights.....thanks either way....

**................scrollview..........................**

```
var editInfoView : UIScrollView = {

    let view = UIScrollView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.contentSize.height = 700
    view.backgroundColor = tableBackGroundColor
    view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 220, width: 375, height: 400)

    return view
}()
```

**.......................label...................**

```
vehicleNumberLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    vehicleNumberLabel.textColor = .white
    vehicleNumberLabel.text = "Vehicle Number"
    vehicleNumberLabel.textAlignment = .left

    editInfoView.addSubview(vehicleNumberLabel)

    vehicleNumberLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: editInfoView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    vehicleNumberLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: editInfoView.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
    vehicleNumberLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160).isActive = true
    vehicleNumberLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
```

**.....................button................................**

```
vehicleNumberButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    vehicleNumberButton.setTitleColor(tableTextColor, for: .normal)
    vehicleNumberButton.setTitle("Vehicle Number", for: .normal)
    vehicleNumberButton.tintColor = tableTextColor
    vehicleNumberButton.backgroundColor = tableTextColor

    editInfoView.addSubview(vehicleNumberButton)

    vehicleNumberButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: editInfoView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    vehicleNumberButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: editInfoView.topAnchor, constant: 400).isActive = true
    vehicleNumberButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 600).isActive = true
    vehicleNumberButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 255).isActive = true
```

Comment: Why you add the constrains after you add it to the view? Maybe you should first add it to the view, after you setted the constrains

Comment: Jonathan, i add constraints after adding it to the view because if i add to the view before, it gives me this error (Thread 1: signal SIGABRT). And this way works just fine for label but not for the button?

Comment: Ah okay, in wich function do you add the buttons and labels? In viewDidLoad?

Comment: i declare them in VC, define in viewdidload and add to the view in a seperate method just for constraints and setup, same for labels and button

Comment: Take a look at this, i thik you should add your Elements in the `init` function: https://medium.com/written-code/creating-uiviews-programmatically-in-swift-55f5d14502ae

Comment: ok i will give it a try, thanks for looking out pal

Comment: still no luck! didnt work

Comment: Why aren’t you implementing the scroll view using auto layout as well?

Comment: the reason is that i am very new at software development and swift as well so i am not well versed with auto layout etc

Answer (score 1):

Although I cannot determine the root cause of your issue with the code and explanation provided I suspect the frame of your `UIScrollView()` is zero after `viewDidAppear(_:)` adding subviews to a `CGRect.zero` can cause some strange behavior with the layout engine. When we create constraints programmatically we are creating a combination of inequalities, equalities, and priorities to restrict the view to a particular frame. If a the value of these constraint equations is incorrect it changes how your relating views appear. Its good practice to avoid the use of `leftAnchor` and `rightAnchor` as well, because views may flip direction based on language (writing direction) and user settings.

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var editInfoScrollView : UIScrollView = {
        let view = UIScrollView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        view.isScrollEnabled = true
        view.contentSize.height = 700
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
        // Does nothing because `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`
        // Instead, set the content size after activating constraints in viewDidAppear
        //view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 220, width: 375, height: 400)
        return view
    }()

    var vehicleNumberLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textColor = UIColor.black
        label.text = "Vehicle Number"
        label.textAlignment = .left
        return label
    }()

    lazy var vehicleNumberButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.tag = 1
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("Go to Vehicle", for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = UIColor.white
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 30 // about half of button.frame.height
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        button.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        button.layer.masksToBounds = true
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handelButtons(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        self.setupSubviews()

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.editInfoScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 700.0)
    }

    func setupSubviews() {
        self.view.addSubview(editInfoScrollView)
            editInfoScrollView.addSubview(vehicleNumberLabel)
            editInfoScrollView.addSubview(vehicleNumberButton)

        let spacing: CGFloat = 12.0

        let constraints:[NSLayoutConstraint] = [

            editInfoScrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor),
            editInfoScrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400.0),
            editInfoScrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
            editInfoScrollView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: 220.0),

            vehicleNumberLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: editInfoScrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: spacing),
            vehicleNumberLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: editInfoScrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -spacing),
            vehicleNumberLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: editInfoScrollView.centerXAnchor, constant: -50),
            vehicleNumberLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 75.0),

            vehicleNumberButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: editInfoScrollView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.66),
            vehicleNumberButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 65.0),
            vehicleNumberButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vehicleNumberLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: spacing),
            vehicleNumberButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: editInfoScrollView.centerXAnchor),

        ]

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }



    @objc func handelButtons(_ sender: UIButton) {

        switch sender.tag {
        case 0:
            print("Default button tag")
        case 1:
            print("vehicleNumberButton was tapped")
        default:
            print("Nothing here yet")
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: @vgvishesh231 did above code help resolve the issue?

Comment: brother your code works in iphone, so i guess i will rewrite my whole view based on that, imma let ya know soon, really appreciate it

Comment: this works but partly, i can now add button but their size is a big rectangle and overlap others which is not changeable, i am gonna try to use label and make it touchable etc